# jvisualvm not displaying thread tab

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I'm unable to see threads menu tab and also profiler and sampler are disabled state and getting message "profiling is not supported by this JVM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the production server, the problem with jvisualVM is, java application is running on 32-bit JDK1.8, and I opened JVisualVM present in 64-bit JDK(1.8)'s bin folder. (simply they have 32,64-bit JDK's)

So make sure when you are running your java application on 32-bit JDK, use JvisualVM from 32-bit JDK only.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem, and I solved it by running JVisualVM as administrator.  My application had been started this way too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 64 bit JVisualVM when you are running java application on 32 bit JVM.